Share external URL on Meeting Stage using teams-js
I'm currently developing a Teams App and came across this sample:
const appContentUrl = "https://www.bing.com/";

microsoftTeams.meeting.shareAppContentToStage((err, result) => {
    if (result) {
        // handle success
    }
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }
}, appContentUrl);

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/build-apps-for-teams-meeting-stage?tabs=desktop#example
When trying to show bing.com on meeting stage, I currently get the following error:
API is not supported in current context-Provided URL is invalid
Just for testing this, I'm allowing all domains on my manifest.
"validDomains": [
    "*"
],

Is it posible to show directly on meeting stage any URL (using microsoftTeams.meeting.shareAppContentToStage) or can I just show an URL between my Teams App?
This works just fine for me:
microsoftTeams.meeting.shareAppContentToStage((error) => {
    if (error) {
        // handle error
    }
}, `${window.location.origin}`);


The microsoftTeams.meeting.shareAppContentToStage method is designed to share content from your Teams app to the meeting stage, not to display arbitrary URLs. This method allows you to share content that is hosted within your Teams app.

Using external URL will give you 501 error. However with ${window.location.origin}, which is the origin of the current window. This would work because it's sharing content from your app, which is within the Teams context.
